# Perl SOAP::Lite server basics

Tags: perl, soap

I'm trying to write a soap server with SOAP::Lite to work with existing soap clients (specifically tr-069 dsl modems), but it's unclear how incoming xml triggers calls.  The soap lite mail list moderator is being slow about adding me to their list, so I thought I'd see if anyone here can help point me in the right direction...

For starters, I'm getting:

```
<faultstring>Unrecognized header has mustUnderstand attribute set to 'true'</faultstring>
```

which I suspect means that I haven't defined a function to handle something that it wants handled.  The handler code (based on the example in the SOAP::Server man page):

```
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::CGI
    ->dispatch_to('PeakACS')
    ->handle;
BEGIN {
    package PeakACS;
    use vars qw(@ISA);
    @ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Server::Parameters);
    use SOAP::Lite;

    my $debugging = 1;
    my $console = 0;
    my $prog_id = 'peakacs';
    my $log = DebugLog->new($prog_id, $debugging, $console);
    $log->debug_msg('info', 'handle', '%s', 'handler setup');

    sub ID {
        $log->debug_msg('info', 'id', '%s', 'got an id');
    }

    sub Header {
        $log->debug_msg('info', 'header', '%s', 'heading');
    }

    sub Inform {
        $log->debug_msg('info', 'inform', '%s', 'informing');
    }
}
```

If I understand SOAP right (which is far from a given), the  tag should translate into a call to Inform - the top of the xml request looks like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cwmp="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-0">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <cwmp:ID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">1539095918</cwmp:ID>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <cwmp:Inform>
        <DeviceId>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set mustUnderstand attribute to some entity in Header, do this:

```
$sheader = SOAP::Header->name('someEntity');
$sheader->mustUnderstand(1);
```

And when calling a method:

```
$soap->someMethod($sheader,@request);
```

Which produces:

```
<soap:Header>
  <someEntity soap:mustUnderstand="1" />
</soap:Header>
```